# IntelliJ Structural Search in PhpStorm to find specific function used within foreach block

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, php-7, structural-search

I need to find all `foreach` blocks wherever I have used `current()` function inside of it. Below is sample code block, which should get find.

```
$x=12;
foreach ($array as &$val)
{
    $cur=current($array);
    $x=$x+$cur;
    echo $cur;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
foreach ($statement$) {
$st1$
$var$ = current($arr$);
$st2$
}
```

[image]

Test code:

```
<?php

$x=12;
foreach ($array as &$val)
{
    $cur=current($array);
    $x=$x+$cur;
    echo $cur;
}

foreach ($array as &$val)
{
    $cur=current($array);
}

foreach ($array as &$val) {
    $x=$x+$cur;

    $cur = current($array);
}

foreach ($array as &$val) {
    $x=$x+$cur;
    echo $cur;
    echo $cur;
    $cur = current($array);
}

foreach ($array as &$val) {
    $x=$x+$cur;
    echo $cur;
    echo $cur;
}
```

Result:

[image]

**NOTES:**

1. You can change `Search target` from "Complete match" to some specific placeholder/variable and it will highlight only that place instead of the whole `foreach` block...
2. That rule will not find places where `current()` is used without assignment or in a some different way (it has to be `$someVar = current($someArray);`).

   You may create a separate rule for that (I'm not sure right now how can they be merged together though), e.g.

```
foreach ($statement$) {
$st1$
current($arr$);
$st2$
}
```